# prevent metavalues for input ports in VHDL simulation

Tags: vhdl, best-practice

In my VHDL design I have entities with port definitions similar to this:

```
entity dummy is
  port( cpl : cplxRecord_t )
end entity

type cplxRecord_t is record
   r1 : anotherRecord_t;
   vec: unsigned;
   lin: std_logic;
   ...
end record
```

in the architecture I use some standard functions for `unsigned`, e.g. `to_integer(cpl.vec)`. These complain during simulation startup `Metavalue detected. Returning ...`. I would like to eliminate the cause of these warnings. So far my only idea is to assign a default value to that port. However having to define each element feels like a bad solution, making htis a maintenance headache when elements are added to/removed from the record. Is there some way to initialize the port with all '0' (Zero)?

Q: How do I prevent `Metavalue detected` warnings, caused by unsigned ports being uninitialized `U` during design loading and processesd by `to_integer`?

P.S.: I am using modelsim. And this font makes it hard to differntiate between letter o and zero. O0o

Comment: What are you trying to program?  What compiler are you using?  Keywords aren't where most go to figure out whatyou're talking about.  The question should stand alone

Comment: @ScottSeidman: I added the tool and tried to write the question as a sentence with its own paragraph, however I feel that this makes it worse in this case as there needs to be some explanation why I dont want to just initialize every port for design loading. I am trying to build a cache, but I do not see how this matters. And I do not understand what you are trying to tell me with " Keywords aren't where most go to figure out whatyou're talking about", would you mind to elaborate?

Comment: The usual way to do this is to write a function that converts things like H to a 1.  Of course, other values like X and U should throw errors.

Comment: @DavidKessner: well given that I am lazy, I think `unsigned` fits better than `std_ulogic_vec` and the problem occurs only during startup (first delta cycles after design is loaded) and is not a problem in operation since the other units drive the inputs only to valid levels (0,1) I think that adding a conversion function would a) be a bit over the top and b) the problem is caused by the port reading `U` during startup in the first place.

Comment: Also, it helps to initialize your signals at startup, when you declare them.  For example "signal foo_bar :std_logic := '0';".  That way they have valid levels even before the simulation starts.

Comment: @DavidKessner: that is what I am asking about. The problem is i have a unconstrained record (vhdl2008), which i constrain, it has 15 entries which are e.g. integer, and are just fine without defining them (just binding to the left most value). I would like to only initialize the element of the record that is of type `unsigned` without having to define the rest. Is there a shortcut, or do I always have to assign the entire record for initialization. (I know there is others, but what if there are `std_logic` AND other `subrecords` mixed, I am not aware of a way to apply others then)

Comment: @ted, Just think about where in your question a reader who doesn't know VHDL will figure out they're looking at VHDL

Comment: @ScottSeidman: now I see, I am sorry about that, it should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you have to assign the whole record.  In the past I've created initialisation constants for my records which ease this problem.

As a workaround (in Modelsim at least, probably Aldec as well) you can use a small TCL function to start off your simulation.  This function can disable those warnings, run for 1 ps, then re-enable the warnings and run the rest of the simulation.

Comment: I will look into both. It seems there is no silver bullet... (maybe a way to set defaults for records globally??)